# Subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I need to calculate $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_A{(|x|(1-|x|))^{(1/n)}arctg(ny)\over{1+x^2+y^2}} dxdy$, where

$A = \{w\in \Bbb{R^2}: |w|\le \sin(3\cdot \angle(w,e_1)) \}$ where $e_1=(0,1)\in \Bbb{R^2}$. I know that I have to use Lebesgue's theorem and I know that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=$$\pm\pi\over2(1+x^2+y^2)$ depending on $sgn(y)$. But I got problem with understanding set $A$.

Comment: What is this $\angle$ thing? It seems as an uncommon markup.

Comment: This is angle sign

Comment: Ok, then what means $3\angle(w,e_1)$?

Comment: 3*(Angle between vector $w$ and vector $e_1$)

Comment: Ok, but what is the $3$ then?

Comment: I've just edited

Comment: Ok, but what means the $3$ in the $3\angle(w,e_1)$? $w$ is a vector, okay. $e_1$ is also a vector, okay. Their angle is $\angle(w,e_1)$, okay. But what is this $3$?

Comment: I understand this as 3 times (that angle). Just a factor. Like 3 * $\pi$

Comment: Ok, thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I should've written it in other way so that there are no doubts what it means ;)

Comment: Next problem: you can make integral over a function, but it is not a function, it is a set. Maybe you want to calculate the area of this 2D set?

Comment: I need to find $\int_A (complicated function)$ and I'll manage to do that if I know how $A$ looks like. That mistake must come from my poor level of English

Comment: What do I say instead?

Comment: Also my English is not very fine, I think there is no problem with yours. I think the solution (even the solvability) largely depends on $f_{complicated}$, this is why you didn't get an answer long ago.

Comment: Changed :) maybe it's easier to understand now

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with set-theory :)

Comment: Yeah...you're right, thanks

Comment: So what exactly do you understand about this problem and what specifically causes your confusion?

Comment: What I don't know is how to make set $A$ easier to cooperate with. If I understand what is $A$, I'll calculate the integral on my own